# How to use a yml file in my plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Lets say my file lives in the `config` folder and it's called `config/foo.yml`. I want to write in that file something like this:

```
development:
  status: developing
  foo: dev-bar

production:
  status: on-air
  foo: prod-bar
```

And then, I want my plugin to read this file and take the correct configuration values according to the environment the app is running in that very time.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [YAML#load_file](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/classes/YAML.html#M001842):

```
options = YAML.load_file('options.yml')
#=> { :development => { :status => 'developing', :foo => 'dev-bar' }, :production => { ... }
```

Comment: But how can I know what environment is being used in running time?

Comment: use `Rails.env` (the newer version of `RAILS_ENV`)

Comment: How does load_file know where to find 'options.yml'?